# gitlab upload to generic fails on .zip

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an upload `gitlab-ci.yaml` routine which I got from a gist.. but getting an error.. anyone have some idea how to upload a .zip to generic?  do I need to change token types ? I am on gitlab.com with their provided runners

```
# Refer to: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/tree/master/docs/examples/release-assets-as-generic-package/
upload:
  stage: upload
  image: curlimages/curl:latest
  script:
    - ls -la
    - |
      PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g')
      PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
      curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --upload-file ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.zip ${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.zip
      echo 'Package uploaded!'
```

here's the erroring run

```
$ PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g') # collapsed multi-line command
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1861k  100    27  100 1861k     44  3100k -{"error":"file is missing"}-:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3102k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80 after 1 ms: Connection refused
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out there was a space in the string.. breaking the URL

so I added

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=$(cat package.json | grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g' | xargs )
```